# What are good colors for illustrating Up and Down?

Tags: color

Imagine a curtain, and two strings. Pulling one string brings it down, pulling the other brings it up. Usually in office environments, these two strings are the same color and this makes it so users pull the wrong string 50% of the time.

Any color ideas for these strings to illustrate Up and Down, if there are any? I'm aware that just giving them two different colors would solve the problem once the user learns which one does what thing, but any way to help a first time user?

Comment: Curtains open sideways; I suspect you're asking about blinds. But I've never seen a blind with a string to pull for up and another for down: all the ones I've seen are roller blinds with a single loop of string, or Venetian blinds with a pair of strings (for some reason I've never understood) joined together and a ratchet mechanism that means you pull the strings to raise the blind and un-ratchet them to allow the blind to lower itself under its own weight.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Technically, there are types of curtains which are raised and lowered, see [Austrian curtain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_curtain#Austrian).

Comment: From the title alone I would say [blue and brown](http://imgur.com/jCkP7oU), but as always, context matters.

Comment: Keep in mind that many can't see red or green.

Comment: The more I thought about this question, I realized I don't know what kind of blinds you are actually talking about. I can't think of any blinds that operate with a two-separate string process where one raises, one lowers. They're usually two strings working together in tandem or they are a continuous pulley. So now I'm curious: what kind of blinds are we talking about?

Comment: Oh, I see David already mentioned this. So I second that. I think we may be trying to come up with answers for a fictional product. :)

Comment: @DavidRicherby FYI, the 'pair' of strings is so that the blinds are supported on each side. If you just had one string in the center, you couldn't keep the blind level. They used to be connected at the end (to form a loop) but that was a choking hazard for children who'd get wrapped up in them.

Comment: Does the concept have to hold for jalousies? Because they are closing and opening into two directions?

Comment: Dont forget about the color-blind out there..

Comment: Why don't you just have a tag attached to each string that will read up/down?

Comment: @DA01 I don't think you have to worry about it being a fictional product. See my comment above.

Comment: @called2voyage that's only 'one' string, though, right? You pull it down, curtain goes up. You release it up, curtain goes down.

Comment: @DA01 I see no reason it *has* to be made that way.

Comment: @called2voyage this is a completely separate conversation, but AFAIK, that *is* the way they are made. I've never seen a blind where two separate strings controlled the direction the blind moves in. Instead, there's one string (or a group of strings acting as one) that either a) moves up and down directly opposite of the direction the curtain is going or b) is in a loop that controls a roll-up shade (so has two 'sides, but still one string). I certainly could be wrong--I've just never in my life seen the type of shade/curtain the OP is describing.

Comment: @DA01 Your two-sides/one-string example could be described as two "strings", but you're right--we're digressing from the main conversation.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don't think the scenario being proposed actually exists. If the OP could share some real world examples, that would improve the question greatly.

Comment: How about conical beads on the end of each string pointing in opposite directions?

Comment: User feedback, when making an error, is fairly instantaneous so there is little need to devise a color coded system to prevent the problem in the first place.

Comment: @DA01 That seems like a ridiculous reason to close. Have you personally seen every type of curtain that exists? Maybe OP made them in his workshop for his house or is planning to do so. Even if not does it have to be a real product to be a legitimate UX question? His first sentence says "Imagine a curtain, and two strings" he could just be using them for context and understanding, because after all the question is really about colors representing up and down.

Comment: @DasBeasto real UX requires context. Context would help this question. (If the question isn't actually about blinds, and is only asking what colors represent up and down, that's a different question with likely different answers (mainly: no, there are no specific colors that represent up and down))

Comment: @DA01 if he showed you a picture of a curtain exactly as he described would it change the question in any way?

Comment: @DasBeasto yes. Context changes everything.

Comment: @DA01 He provided the context verbally, just because you can convert his words into images in your head doesn't mean it isn't a UX question or there would be a "Must provide pictures" rule.

Comment: from all the confusion in the comments I suppose some kind of illustration or pictures would be helpful for explaning how these curtains (or blinds) work

Answer (score 108, accepted):

With your examples of Curtains, I would go with **Black** and **White**.

Easy psychology and Cosmetic.

**Black:**

If it's too bright in the day, you'll happen to easily see the Black beads/string and it also means pulling it down will darken the room.

**White:**

If it's getting too dark, White will be easier to notice and will signify that pulling it will lighten the room.

I'm not an Interior designer, but it wouldn't blend in with the curtain colors as well to confuse the user.

Comment: Nice idea. This also ensures that the curtains won't clash with any existing color scheme in the room.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I normally see beads today with curtains having White. They could only make the other end Black.

Comment: +1 a nice bonus is you could have the same convention for horizontal blinds. Black -> darker -> blinds close / move closer together, white -> lighter -> blinds open / move further apart. I doubt anyone would guess the meaning first time, but it'd help people remember 2nd and 3rd+ time.

Comment: Wow! I didn't think of that at all! Brilliant!

Comment: Thank you! Far too often folks forget about us color-blind people!  :-)

Comment: +1...  An alternative in the same avenue, could also go yellow (sun) and perhaps a dark-brown rather than black.

Comment: Yellow and Black could have been a solution but since most curtains are of a particular color, it wouldn't go well if the curtain was say, a lighter shade of orange or yellow.

Comment: Over here walls tend to be white and a white string on a white wall is hard to see no matter how bright it is.

Comment: This doesnt' answer OPs question as black isn't a color :P

Comment: Hahah! It does however bring emphasis to the theory of no light ;)

Comment: You could come up with dozens of different explanations to explain that white is "close" and black is "open" or the reverse. Is this like these standardized tests where you need to guess which answer is the "most correct" answer out of multiple correct answers, basically you need to guess what the designer had specifically in mind when s/he designed the thing to use it effectively?

Answer (score 20):

No, I don't think that any colors inherently represent up and down. But I'll take a stab in the dark here:

**1. White/Black**

Since in this particular case you're asking about a curtain in an office environment, I assume it will be used to block a window, in turn blocking out light. So when the user pulls the curtain down it will get darker and when they pull it up it will get brighter. So White can represent up for the brightness and black can be down for darkness.

**2. Red/Blue**

Heat rises, heat is represented by red. So to represent the string to raise the curtain, make that string red. Blue being cold, being the opposite of the rising heat, will represent the string that lowers the curtain.

**Let me be perfectly clear,** I do not think either of these will help first time users too much, I think they may be just **slightly** better than the two strings of the same color.

Comment: haha beat me to it by a second

Comment: +1 Red/Blue may be better for dark environments since a black string may be difficult to see.

Comment: For me: blue = noon; red -> sunset -> down

Comment: Heat doesn't rise, *hot fluid* rises; and I don't think the logic of this colour coding would be obvious to many people.

Comment: @nekomatic I agree it wouldn't be very useful that's why I added the last sentence. But to most people heat rises it doesn't get that scientific, so fluid or not I doubt it will matter.

Comment: The bigger issue, IMHO, is I now have red and blue strings on all my windows. Now I have to get matching pillows. :)

Comment: The red and blue doesn't seem particularly useful to me from either a temperature or up/down perspective. When a thing gets a bit hot, it burns red, when it gets very hot, it burns blue. Red also symbolises different things for different cultures, such as representing the earth (which is generally found by looking down) on the Australian Aboriginal flag. To me, blue represents the sky, and thus up, but to the English, the sky is grey but there is plenty of ocean below them for blue to mean down.

Answer (score 20):

It doesn't matter. All that matters is that they are **different** so the user can differentiate them.

There is no particular color combo to correlate with up and down. You could come up with a number of them, but they wouldn't be in any way universally agreed upon.

If you want maximum differentiation, then black and white.

But note that you're also going to have an aesthetic challenge here. Window blinds are both functional and aesthetic items. People probably don't want colored strings hanging from their windows. :)

Comment: I do see a clear correlation: up = open = let the day light in = white, down = close = keep the night out or simulate the night during the day = black. Another similar correlation is up = air = light blue or white, down = earth = brown or black

Comment: @anneb there are plenty of correlations we can come up with individually. But they aren't going to be universally intuitive. Also keep in mind that blinds serve multiple purposes. It's not just about blocking light, but also blocking views. Some blinds are opaque, some are translucent. Etc.

Answer (score 7):

I do not think the colors themselves are as important as their contrast.  Shouldn't a good UI mimic the natural environment as much as possible?  If so, since, generally, lighter colors are up and darker colors are down, a lighter color for up and a darker one for down seems appropriate.

Comment: Specifically, sky blue for up and midnight blue for down would seem very appropriate, like turning the light levels up and down respectively.

Comment: Sky blue for up and the color of the walls would also be a good choice (if the walls aren't white anyway) - pull the blue cord to make the room become brighter and bluer, pull the orange cord, and the light reflecting off the orange paint on the walls will take over.

Answer (score 7):

I would go with the string shape. I'd make it like so:

```
  ||     __||__
  /\     \    /
 /  \     \  /
/_  _\     \/
  ||     __||__
  /\     \    /
 /  \     \  /
/_  _\     \/
  ||       ||
  \\______//
   --------
```

The concept modeled here is the "right direction" (appropriate). If you touch the string and slide your fingers along it you receive tactile feedback: smooth or harsh.

The harsh one could be intuitively seen as the bad one. The smooth as the proper one. I would then encode that pulling in the "right" direction would translate to the same movement of curtain. If the curtain is up and someone pulls down, using the right string, then the curtains go down.

Comment: Are you saying you've pictured the down string?

Comment: What do I do with that string? Do the arrows mean I need to let that string up? Or is it saying that if I pull it in the opposite direction of the arrows, the blinds will move in that direction? (Point being this isn't necessarily intuitive).

Comment: @SamuelEdwinWard: Yes, it was the down string. I've added the up string as well.

Comment: @DA01: Good point, there is a second competing concept here, which could confuse the user. Originally I was thinking about "a surface with different smoothness depending on the direction" and the arrows are just one possible shape. Like a cat's fur, there is certainly one right direction if you want to please it

Comment: I have another idea! What if we can design a string, which has drastically different friction depending on the direction? The cat fur is exactly that. If we had such strings, we could grab both strings, apply some down force. Naturally, we apply the force evenly on both strings, but because of the friction differences, it is applied unevenly - such that the high friction string moves with the hand and the low friction one moves against the hand direction.

Comment: @Rekin I like this solution as it answers the "one-string" issue, although at first glance it is still a bit confusing as you have to pull down on the up string to make it go up. So first time users may be confused, this would be helpful for repeat users though.

Answer (score 5):

Taking a cue from **elevators**:

- White or green for up
- Red for down

[image: elevator arrows]

Comment: As that graphic shows, the colors are universally applied. Perhaps it's a regional thing?

Comment: This also has strong [stock market connotation](https://www.stockmarketeye.com/blog/reading-colors-in-stock-charts-green-and-red-explained/) which is hardwired in many people's brains

Answer (score 3):

red for up ( hot air rises ) blue for down ( cool air settles ) 
you can also create arrow like patterns on the string to reinforce the message.

Comment: What does hot air have to do with it? I would have guessed blue for heaven and red for hell.

Comment: @200_success red is hot, and hot air rises. Blue is cool, and cool air settles. Thus red is up and blue is down.

Comment: @JacobRaihle But hot air is clear, and cold air is also clear. The association is non-obvious, and alternate associations exist, making it a poor UX design choice.

Comment: @200_success we arent all religious you know,you can say you associate blue with the water and red with tomatoes,therefore it doesn't make sense in your opinion. In UX the **main goal** is to make an interface easy to understand for the majority of people.

Comment: @downrep_nation THANK YOU! i found it weird that my association was less credible....none of these examples are great as it is not something that exists, at this point it is about conditioning the user more so than making any right association.

Answer (score 3):

I think Green and Red would work.

People could associate them with thumbs up and thumbs down, and thus curtain up / curtain down. I believe everyone has seen a green thumbs up and red thumbs down button or similar, so they could get it right the first time.

The negative side is, that the red/green might also associate good with green and bad with red.

Comment: Except green/red is the most common of all colorblindess.

Answer (score 2):

Thinking outside the box, but you could add physical arrows to the strings. Or you could have a paper behind the strings that shows which string is which.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't make the one string thicker and the other string slim with the black/white color code in one of the answers here.

Usually on mechanically operated curtains which opens up and down side, closing it takes less effort than opening it because when closing it all comes down, so gravitational force helps them to close and come down.

It will only take user less than 10 seconds to figure out, why one thick and the other is slim.

Hope you are getting my point. Also you are taking care of the blinds and color blinds with this solution

Answer (score 2):

I have four suggestions with various reasons:

1. blue and green.

Blue = sky = up
Green = grass = down

2. For places unfamiliar with blue skies and green grass

Brown = smog = up
Grey = road = down

3. from traffic lights

Red = above = up
Green = below = down

4. Final suggestion from rainbows

Red = first color = up
Violet = last color = down

Of course glow in the dark dye will be immensely useful in this context.

Comment: *Brown = smog = up Grey = road = down* not sure if thats sad or not, but i would never understand brown is up. and i know what living in a smog covered city is like... also most people know the sky is blue

Comment: Blue sky/Green grass may be semi-intuitive (about as much as any of these colors can signify) but the rest of these I would have no idea unless you explained them to me. (i.e. brown could be wood/gray could be smoke rising from it so opposite direction of your interpretation, violet has a higher frequency than red so should be up comparatively, etc.) Although I like the creative thinking.

Comment: I think the fact that you have 4 suggestions somewhat shows that there are no universal colors for this. :)

Answer (score 2):

Directions aren't typically associated with colours ever, so whatever you pick will be arbitrary. However, if you make it obvious which one you have to pull to make it go up or down (the natural thing would be to pull the higher of the two), that would no doubt help 1st time users immensely.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it might be able to signify the opening of the curtains through effectively mini images of the curtains opening. You have the curtains as a dark colour and then a light colour between then slowly expands between each section of the rope.

This assumes it being one continuous cord rather than two separate cords.

However I think you could split it in the middle and have on one half on one rope and the other half on the other rope.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

Blue = Up Green = Down

Blue is the sky. Green is the grass.

Comment: That's a good first thought but can you expand on that. Any testing of this idea? Any research of how it's interpreted by users?

Comment: @Mayo I'm not aware of any testing of these colors for this application. It's a first gut instinct. If I were "trem", I would be focusing on a movement solution or a more explicit visual solution. Regarding movement for example, if the user's cursor passes over the up button, it could bounce up slightly.

Answer (score -1):

When talking about general terms like up and down there is no real color associated with those words.

If you want the user to experience something on your site you have to set up the rules from the moment they enter. If this were me I would try this.

Have the images or graphics on you page contain a vertical css gradient. An example would be to start with the top being blue and the bottom being green.

Doing this sets a precedent for the user and gives your concept validation and anyone navigates your site.

This will be your global rule for up and down on your site. Try it with various elements (menu bar, icon background color, site background etc). Then when you create your up and down elements you have a basis and validation for your design.

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: Hi, I downvoted this answer as it doesn't really explain why a gradient of those colors helps represent up and down. Also as a lesser point, in this particular question it appears he is searching for more of a physical representation (not on a computer) so this answer isn't entirely relevant, but my main issue is the lack of explanation.

Comment: Too bad I am being marked down so heavily for this. I was only trying to help. I just started a few days ago and this is a very discouraging experience. I should have just kept my opinions to myself.

Comment: @user3174713 Don't be discouraged, downvotes are a very common and necessary part of the StackExchange experience. I'm a very active member and have posted many questions and answers and have had them downvoted regularly. You can't take it personally it is just the only way to regulate and make this a successful site. Your answer is helpful, especially after the edit (very appreciated), just not the best answer for this particular question so this answer goes down and the best answer goes up.

Comment: Ok thank you. I will still try an give better answers!